# control scoping of arguments supplied to lm() from whithin a function called by lapply

Tags: r, lm, scoping

I have a function that takes a dataset, extracts different variables, and then makes linear models from those variables (it expects the response in the last column). I want the `data` argument of the calls for these models to use objects in the global environment so that I can manipulate them with other functions outside this function. The following gives the expected behavior when provided with a single dataset.

```
make_mods <- function(dataset) {
  make_mod <- function(x){
    response <- names(dataset)[length(dataset)]
    form <- paste0(response, " ~ ", x)
    form <- as.formula(form)
    bquote( lm(.(form), data = .(d_sub)) ) # Unevaluated to show output
  }
  d_sub <- substitute(dataset)
  vars <- names(dataset)[-length(dataset)]
  mods <- lapply(vars, make_mod)
  return(mods)
}

# Make some different datasets
ex1 <- ex2 <- ex3 <- mtcars[c(3,4,6,1)] 
new_data <- function(x) {
  x + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = sd(x))
}
ex2[-length(ex2)] <- lapply(ex2[-length(ex2)], new_data)
ex3[-length(ex3)] <- lapply(ex3[-length(ex3)], new_data)

make_mods(ex1)
```

I also want to be able to use this function within `lapply`

```
# List of datasets for testing function with lapply
ex_l <- mget(c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3"))
lapply(ex_l, make_mods)
```

But here the model calls end up looking like this: `lm(mpg ~ disp, data = X[[i]])` and, of course, this model call doesn't evaluate in the default environment (the actual function evaluates the model call in the function). The desired output is a list of lists of models that look like: `lm(mpg ~ disp, data = ex_l[["ex1"]])`, i.e., they have valid calls with `data` arguments that reference data frames in the global environment.

I've experimented with passing names to `lapply` and different wrapper functions for calling `make_mods` from `lapply` but it seems like my function, in using `substitute` only gives the expected behavior when called from the global environment. I'm new to working with scoping and environments. **How can I get my function to give the desired `lm` call both when passed a data frame from the global environment, and when passed data frames from within `lapply`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I could think of was to add an if statement to my make mods function that tests if the input is a call or not. If it's a call, it expects it to be a call for a dataset in the global environment.

```
make_mods <- function(dataset) {
  make_mod <- function(x){
    response <- names(dataset)[length(dataset)]
    form <- paste0(response, " ~ ", x)
    form <- as.formula(form)
    bquote( lm(.(form), data = .(d_sub)) )
  }
  if(is.call(dataset)) {
    d_sub <- dataset
    dataset <- eval(dataset)
  } else {
    d_sub <- substitute(dataset)
  }
  vars <- names(dataset)[-length(dataset)]
  mods <- lapply(vars, make_mod)
  return(mods)
}
```

Then I can use `lapply` like this:

```
out <- lapply(names(ex_l), function(x){
        g <- bquote(ex_l[[.(x)]])
        make_mods(g)
    })

names(out) <- names(ex_l)
```

which gives me this:

```
$ex1
$ex1[[1]]
lm(mpg ~ disp, data = ex_l[["ex1"]])

$ex1[[2]]
lm(mpg ~ hp, data = ex_l[["ex1"]])  

$ex1[[3]]
lm(mpg ~ wt, data = ex_l[["ex1"]])

<<output truncated>>
```

Maybe not an elegant solution, but it's working.